# Nhibernate: How create a <bag> on two classes for same class child?

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, hibernate-mapping

I have a class/table named "Comment"

```
<class name="Comment">
<id name="Id">
  <generator class="guid"/>
</id>
<property name="ReferenceId" index="Comment_ReferenceId_Index" />
<property name="Contents" length="1024" />
```

And I need to create a bag of comments on several other classes like Contract

```
<class name="Contract">
<id name="Id">
  <generator class="guid"/>
</id>
<property name="Status"/>    
<bag name="Comments">
  <key column="ReferenceId" />
  <one-to-many class="Comment" />
</bag>
```

Or Application:

```
<class name="Application">
<id name="Id">
  <generator class="guid"/>
</id>
<property name="Status" />
<bag name="Comments">
  <key column="ReferenceId" />
  <one-to-many class="Comment" />
</bag>
```

But this mapping give me only one foreign key, how can i create the collection to have comments on several classes?

Comment: Not sure if I understand. ReferenceId is a foreign key to which table?

Comment: Sorry, when I use the Tool.hbm2ddl only generate one foreing key, i'm not sure if should create two or nothing and use other reference mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was:

Set the name of the foreign key to "none" and then hibernate don't create the FK but tracks the references.

```
<class name="Contract">
<id name="Id">
  <generator class="guid" />
</id>
<property name="Status" />    
<bag name="Comments">
  <key column="ReferenceId" foreign-key="none"/>
  <one-to-many class="Comment" />
</bag>
```

Answer (score 0):

With this mapping you get one foreign key because you've explicitly configured it this way. `<key column="...">` is the same `ReferenceId` column for both parent classes, this means that NHibernate is trying to make `ReferenceId` foreign key to both `Application` and `Contract` and this can't be done.

The easiest way is to give your key columns different names like `ContractId` and `ApplicationId`.

If you're trying to have a single `ReferenceId` column that will reference either `Contract` or `Application` and never both of them, you have to add discriminator column to your `Contract` and do `<any>` mapping - [see this article](http://ayende.com/blog/3966/nhibernate-mapping-any).